# How can I get other item not just first one on click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created like a mini shop with 4 items and now I want to change the quantity of that items and be able to add them to a cart I created when I click button + to grab my item id but why is only grabbing me first id how can I get other items id by clicking it on same class for all of them here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Creating ajax request to get all items from the server
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://api.cleverchoice.cc/",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            var html = '';
            response.forEach(function(data){
                html += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 Single_Product" id="'+data["id"]+'">'+
                          '<div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">'+
                            '<img class="card-img-top" src="'+ data["image"] +'" data-holder-rendered="true">'+
                                '<div class="card-body">'+
                                    '<p class="card-text cc-name">'+data["name"]+'</p>'+
                                    '<div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">'+
                                        '<div class="btn-group">'+
                                            '<div class="Qty_Box">'+
                                                '<span class="Qty_Minus">-</span>'+
                                                '<input class="qty_value" type="text" value="1" name="qty">'+
                                                '<span class="Qty_Plus">+</span>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '<label for="cart_drawer_action" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary add_to_cart">Add to cart</label>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<small class="text-muted price">'+data["currency"]+data["price"]+'</small>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>';
            });
            
            $(".Product_List").append(html);

            // Adding quantity
            $(".Qty_Plus").click(function(){
                var id = $(".Single_Product").attr("id");

                console.log(id);

                var i =  $("#"+id+" .qty_value").val() * 1 + 1;
                $("#"+id+" .qty_value").val(i);
            });
            // Decrise quantity
            $(".Qty_Minus").click(function(){
                var id = $(".Single_Product").attr("id");

                if($(".qty_value").val() != 1){
                   var i =  $("#"+id+" .qty_value").val() * 1 - 1;
                   $("#"+id+" .qty_value").val(i);
                }  
            });
            // Add to cart
            $(".add_to_cart").click(function(){
                var id = $(".Single_Product").attr("id");
                console.log(id);

                var image = $("#"+id+" .card-img-top").attr("src");
                var name = $("#"+id+" .cc-name").html();
                var qty = $("#"+id+" .qty_value").val();
                var price = $("#"+id+" .price").html();

                html = '<div class="Cart_Item">'+
                    '<div class="Cart_Img"><img src="'+ image +'" alt="product"/></div>'+
                    '<div class="Cart_Name"><p>'+ name +'</p></div>'+
                    '<div class="Cart_Price"><p>'+ qty +'</p></div>'+
                    '<div class="Cart_Price"><p>'+ price +'</p></div>'+
                    '<div class="Cart_Price"><p>'+ price +'</p></div>'+
                '</div>';

                $(".Cart_Items").append(html);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, change `var id = $(".Single_Product").attr("id");` to `var id = $(this).closest(".Single_Product").attr("id");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `var id = $(".Single_Product").attr("id");` can only return one id from the matching selectors so it always returns the first one.

You can use `siblings('.qty_value')` to target the associated input or `closest('.Qty_Box').find('.qty_value')`

Something like:

```
$(".Qty_Plus").click(function(){
      var $input = $(this).siblings('.qty_value')
      $input.val( +$input.val() +1)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're creating multiple `.Single_Product` elements in the DOM, and reading the `attr()` from a collection within a jQuery object only returns the value from the `first` matching element.

To fix the issue you can use DOM traversal to relate the element which raised the event to those around it by moving through the DOM. In this case, using `closest()` to find  the nearest `.Single_Product` and then `find()` to target the required information.

Note in the example below that I also amended the logic to use delegated event handlers, to save you rebinding the same event handler multiple times.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $container = $('.Product_List');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://api.cleverchoice.cc/",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      let html = response.map(data => `<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 Single_Product" id="${data.id}">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="${data.image}" data-holder-rendered="true" />
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text cc-name">${data.name}</p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="Qty_Box">
                  <span class="Qty_Minus">-</span>
                  <input class="qty_value" type="text" value="1" name="qty">
                  <span class="Qty_Plus">+</span>
                </div>
                <label for="cart_drawer_action" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary add_to_cart">Add to cart</label>
              </div>
              <small class="text-muted price">${data.currency + data.price}</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`);
      $container.append(html);
    }
  });

  // Add quantity
  $container.on('click', '.Qty_Plus', e => {
    $(e.target).closest('.Single_Product').find('.qty_value').val((i, v) => +v + 1);
  });
  
  // Decrease quantity
  $container.on('click', '.Qty_Minus', e => {
    $(e.target).closest('.Single_Product').find('.qty_value').val((i, v) => +v - 1);
  });
  
  // Add to cart
  $container.on('click', '.add_to_cart', e => {
    let $product = $(e.target).closest('.Single_Product');
    var id = $product.prop("id");
    var image = $product.find('.card-img-top').attr("src");
    var name = $product.find('.cc-name').text();
    var qty = $product.find('.qty_value').val();
    var price = $product.find('.price').text();

    html = `<div class="Cart_Item">
      <div class="Cart_Img"><img src="${image}" alt="product"/></div>
      <div class="Cart_Name"><p>${name}</p></div>
      <div class="Cart_Price"><p>${qty}</p></div>
      <div class="Cart_Price"><p>${price}</p></div>
      <div class="Cart_Price"><p>${price}</p></div>
      </div>`;

    $(".Cart_Items").append(html);
  });
});
```

```css
img { height: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Product_List"></div>
<div class="Cart_Items"></div>
```